# Redirect substring of URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I redirect `mydomain.com/asin-123.php` to `new-domain.com/product-reviews/123/`

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^asin-(.*).php$ http://www.amazon.de/product-reviews/$1/?tag=httpswww08e73-21 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But somehow it is not working... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try RedirectMatch directive :

```
 RedirectMatch ^/asin-([^.]+)\.php$ http://newdomain.com/reviews/$1
```

Comment: With some more tuning i managed to use it. Especally i added 301 after the RedirectMatch